# GDAL 2.3.1 is installed but the llinux terminal is using GDAL 2.2.2

Tags: numpy, ubuntu, gdal

I've installed GDAL 2.3.1 using pip on a ubuntu 16.04. The package is in the correct site-packages directory and yet when I run a python script, I receive this error:

```
 Error 1: NUMPY driver was compiled against GDAL 2.3, but the current library 
 version is 2.2
```

When using 'gdal-config --version', the output shows '2.2.2'.

I want to know how to change the version of gdal that linux appears to be using from 2.2.2 to 2.3.1 but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `pip`, sometimes it is confusing to know where things got installed. Try these steps:

```
sudo updatedb
locate gdal
```

You should find the path where gdal stuff has been installed and stored. Once you know it, just export the required path as an environmental variable to your preferred bash script (eg. .bashrc) and re-open the terminal to test `gdal` is working properly. Thus the correct `gdal` version should be called without problems. For `gdal` to be recognized by previous installed software (eg. `Numpy`), it may be necessary to re-install them.